# Incorrect group by and order by merge

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have couple tables joined in MySQL - one has many others.
And try to select items from one, ordered by min values from another table.

Without grouping in seems to be like this:

**Code:**

```
select `catalog_products`.id
     , `catalog_products`.alias
     , `tmpKits`.`minPrice`
from `catalog_products`
left join `product_kits` on `product_kits`.`product_id` = `catalog_products`.`id`
left join (
    SELECT MIN(new_price) AS minPrice, id FROM product_kits GROUP BY id
) AS tmpKits on `tmpKits`.`id` = `product_kits`.`id`
where `category_id` in ('62')
order by product_kits.new_price ASC
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

But when I add group by, I get this:

**Code:**

```
select `catalog_products`.id
     , `catalog_products`.alias
     , `tmpKits`.`minPrice`
from `catalog_products`
left join `product_kits` on `product_kits`.`product_id` = `catalog_products`.`id`
left join (
    SELECT MIN(new_price) AS minPrice, id FROM product_kits GROUP BY id
) AS tmpKits on `tmpKits`.`id` = `product_kits`.`id`
where `category_id` in ('62')
group by `catalog_products`.`id`
order by product_kits.new_price ASC
```

**Result:**

[image]

And this is incorrect sorting!

Somehow when I group this results, I get **id 280 before 281!**

But I need to get:

281|1600.00

280|2340.00

**So, grouping breaks existing ordering!**

Comment: I need them sorted by min prices. and they are sorted.
But group by is breaking this sorting.

Comment: group by `catalog_products.id` will return only one row per id, if you want all of them to be shown then do not use group by just use `order by catalog_products.id, product_kits.new_price`

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: `Group by` always comes after `Order by`, otherwise you get some unexpected errors.

Comment: I understand that `group by` comes before `order by`, but why in this case `group by` breaking sorting? First string should be with price `1600.00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that group by **does not recognize** order by in MySQL.

Actually, what I was doing is really bad practice.
In this case you should use distinct and by catalog_products.*

In my opinion, group by is really useful when you need group result of agregated functions.
Otherwise you should not use it to get unique values.

Answer (score 0):

For one, when you apply the `GROUP BY` to only one column, there is no guarantee that the values in the other columns will be consistently correct. Unfortunately, MySQL allows this type of SELECT/GROUPing to happen other products don't. Two, the syntax of using an `ORDER BY` in a subquery while allowed in MySQL is not allowed in other database products including SQL Server. You should use a solution that will return the proper result each time it is executed.

So the query will be:

For one, when you apply the `GROUP BY` to only one column, there is no guarantee that the values in the other columns will be consistently correct. Unfortunately, MySQL allows this type of SELECT/GROUPing to happen other products don't. Two, the syntax of using an `ORDER BY` in a subquery while allowed in MySQL is not allowed in other database products including SQL Server. You should use a solution that will return the proper result each time it is executed.

So the query will be:

```
   select CP.`id`, CP.`alias`, TK.`minPrice`
    from catalog_products CP
    left join `product_kits` PK on PK.`product_id` = CP.`id`
    left join (
        SELECT MIN(`new_price`) AS "minPrice", `id` FROM product_kits GROUP BY `id`
    ) AS TK on TK.`id` = PK.`id`
    where CP.`category_id` IN ('62')
    order by PK.`new_price` ASC
    group by CP.`id`
```

Comment: Are you kidding me `order by` clause before `group by` as you added `order by product_kits.new_price ASC
group by catalog_products.id`